# C concate string extra space

Tags: c, string

I created a function which basically does the same as `strcat`.

```
void Mystrcat(char* s, char* t)
{
    int j, i=0;
    for ( j = 0; s[j] != '\0'; j++);

    for (i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; i++, j++)
        s[j] = t[i];
}
```

I can't understand what am I missing. The concatenation works except in the last charcarter, I allways get an extra `space` .

```
Input: s = "My        " t="House" , output = "My House "
```

Answer (score 4):

You fail to terminate the output, you never write the `'\0'` at the end. You can make the second loop be the classic copying loop instead:

```
while (s[j++] = t[i++])
  ;
```

This will stop *after* copying the terminator.

Your code probably has undefined behavior, which happens to manifest as an extra space.

Also, if your input really is `"My        "` and `"House"`, the correct output should of course be

```
"My        House"
```

with all the spaces at the end of the input preserved.

As pointed out in a comment, you can't modify a string literal, and you of course need to have the space allocated.

Something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  char s[100] = "My        ", *t = "House";
  Mystrcat(s, t);
  printf("Got '%s'\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
Got 'My        House'
```

as expected.

Comment: Ok for the loop, but wrong for what output should be. More: modifying string literal is not defined (may be non writable).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Can you please clarify the output part, then?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Ah, okay. Also note that there was no string literal in the OP's code, it was kind of pseudo-code. I added a example code and pointed this out, so thanks.